# How can I safely determine the output voltage and current of a transformer?

Tags: power-supply, transformer, high-voltage, tesla-coil

So I am building a Tesla coil with my partner for a senior design project.

We safely ripped out a transformer from a microwave oven. However, after a good amount of research, we were unable to find the maximum output values from the transformer. We know the input values, the standard 120 V and 60 Hz from a US outlet. We need to know the max/peak kV to figure out the capacitance we will need for our primary coil that we need to construct.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Transformer from a microwave oven]

Comment: *We safely ripped out a transformer from a microwave oven* Sure but the safety ends at the very moment when you connect the 120 V AC input to mains voltage when you want to use this transformer. Microwave transformers are designed to deliver a high voltage at significant current levels. Because that's the power going into the Magnetron tube. If you have to ask the rating of this transformer I seriously advise you to first get more experience with (high voltage) electronics before you continue.

Comment: To be clear: without knowing **exactly** what you're doing you should not mess with the transformer from any microwave oven. **They're LETHAL when connected to AC mains**. Are you an electrical engineer? No, then leave these transformers alone. Even electrical engineers don't mess with these.

Comment: well we were going to make a faraday cage and enclose the coil inside it before plugging in to the outlet. we can also just make a small-scale tesla coil without having to deal with these big transformers, a student from a previous year did it and we have been using it as a reference but we're not exactly sure how it is getting the job done with only the 120 V input thats connected straight to what looks like the primary winding.

Comment: Besides being extremely dangerous, IMO this is a poor senior design project, I am surprised that a professor would approve this. There is a lot of "black magic" involved, since the parasitics are difficult to estimate, you can't use always us rigorous engineering math. IMO a senior design project should involve requirements and math/simulations to back-up the design besides successful execution of the design. What are your requirements, lots of cool sparks?

Comment: Have a friend do the measurements for you.

Comment: I'm only a senior in high school as of now and choosing a senior design project is part of the curriculum for Honors Engineering class so my partner and I decided to make a Tesla Coil. At this point of the year I think we can settle to create something small and less dangerous. The defined goal of this project is to demonstrate that electricity can be wirelessly transmitted through air. right now the measurements are based on this program called Tesla Map, I found from teslacoildesign.com

Comment: Posts like this are how every poor Tesla coil design starts...

Answer (score 12):

No. Do not use a Microwave Oven Transformer (MOT) for a Tesla coil.

It is the wrong impedance. The output voltage is too low (around 2kV), spark gaps will not fire reliably. The output current is too high (500mA), if it bites you, you will probably die.

The correct transformer to use is an old style (iron core) Neon Sign Transformer (NST). The output voltage of 15kV is plenty to make very forgiving spark gaps. The output current in the low tens of mA may well be survivable if it bites you.

Comment: For clarification, so a microwave transformer is not high enough voltage to easily make spark gaps, but at the same time high enough voltage to produce hazardous sparks and high enough power to have lethal levels of current behind those sparks?

Comment: @Toor There's a lot of technology to Tesla Coils, technology = knowledge of how to make them work. 2kV will jump very short gaps in air. However, making a reliable gap that size with big copper electrodes to dissipate the heat is *hard*, it's not something experienced coilers attempt, somebody with no experience is doooomed to failure. It is enough to jump through dry clothing, mains will not do that, which is why mains is *relatively* safe, and MOTs are lethal. Once an arc has started, that 500mA will start fires (1kW!) and is 10x the level needed to stop a heart.

Comment: Toor, 2 kV with current capability of 500 mA will easily kill you, and not by "sparks". It's volts that jolt, but mils that kill.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I can buy those newer NSTs but they have GFCI protection in them making them useless on a Tesla coil, although some have figured out a way to bypass that. iron core NSTs are far too expensive for our budget, at least the ones we've looked at. I can't find ones under $100

Comment: @KrutikShah Unfortunately correct. You just can't get the old ones new these days, and used ones are becoming very rare. You might try going onto specialist high voltage forums (SE is not the place for coilers) and seeing if any members can help you out, either with a cheap second-hand one, or even a loaner for the project. You might want to consider buying a car ignition coil, it obviously can't be driven direct from the mains, but it has plenty of volts, and can run a respectable power for a short while. They can come very cheaply second hand.

Comment: @KrutikShah [these](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98152/mot-power-supply-issues?rq=1) are the games people get into when they try to make a MOT-powered TC, once you're up at 4 MOTs, the spark gaps become reasonable. The power level is totally unreasonable.

Comment: @KrutikShah One reasonable way to build a TC with a single MOT is to make a DC coil. Run a pair of doublers from the MOT, using the diodes and caps you get from a bunch of other dismantled microwave ovens, one positive one negative, to get a balanced +/- 5kV. Now with a rotary gap and charging choke, this becomes 20kV on your tank cap. Unfortunately, as it's DC you need the rotary gap, which is tricky mechanically. With the capacitor-backed 10kV DC supply, it's even more lethal than just a MOT. There's nothing to beat an NST for your first TC.

Comment: +1 for the **bites you**.

Comment: They could use a Microwave oven transformer (MOT) if they replace the secondary (and possibly add a magnetic shunt to limit the current, or current-limit using PWM). Can you add anything on this? I've replaced the secondary on MOT's with just a few turns to attempt a spot welder. You could conceivably take two MOT's of similar size and move one transformer's primary to replace the other transformer's secondary to make an isolation transformer -- Right?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD The first words of their question are 'building a TC', so spot-welder MOT transformations are out. It's often been done to take two MOTs, connect their secondaries together, and use the pair as a 1:1 isolation transformer from primary to primary, but that uses up MOTs real fast, and unless you take the shunts out, and under-run the cores, uses reactive VA and quite a bit of power real fast as well.

Answer (score 10):

6170W1D012G is an LG part number. Primary 120v. HT secondary is 2210v 500 mA. If you have to ask, as has been said, you do not know enough to do this safely.

Answer (score 1):

Consider exciting the high voltage secondary (at 60 Hz) and measuring primary voltage to get an idea of the turns ratio.  It should be pretty simple math past that.

I agree with other comments that you might want more experience and/or meaningful oversight from your professors for this project.

Comment: Sure but that does not tell us anything about the power rating of this transformer.

Comment: What was the power rating of the microwave?  You probably can't establish a rating without input from the manufacturer, nameplate information, or testing and knowledge of the construction (insulation temp ratings mostly).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the general question, to suss out the basic specs of a power transformer drive it backwards.  This is how we did it in engineering school with pole transformers.

You apply 120vac to the HV secondary of the transformer, then measure the voltage on the primary.  (Note: Be sure to fuse the 120v supply.)  This will let you calculate the ratio of primary to secondary voltage.  There was also a way to roughly calculate the current capacity while doing this, but it's been nearly 50 years, so I've forgotten that detail.

Comment: Note: This is a microwave oven transformer. It has an HT secondary winding, and also a 3.15v secondary winding for the magnetron cathode heater filament. If attempting a backward measurement, then identifying the right secondary is important, as applying 120v to the 3.15v winding is likely to cause hazardous voltages to appear at the primary, and/or damage the transformer.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage of a microwave oven transformer & the voltage across the capacitor is about 2.1KV The voltage rating should be printed on the capacitor. But like the other guys said: Don't use it for a Tesla Coil. The voltage is too low & the current too high, and it is too dangerous. Use a neon sign transformer. In case you are wondering why such a perfect square wave across the magnetron: The transformer acts like it has an inductor in series. This happens with anything that behaves like a zener and is fed through an inductor, like a fluorescent light, or from a high leakage transformer, like a neon sign tube. The inductor (or transformer secondary) stores energy, then feeds it out into the next 1/2 cycle. When the energy runs out, the potential drops across to the strike voltage of the tube, load voltage (as in a magnetron), or the applied voltage (whichever is less).
[image: Image showing waveforms and voltages from microwave oven transformer]

<sub>Image source: My own experiments - Peter R. McMahon</sub>

Comment: I got the waveforms, using a battery operated CRO with 99 megs of resistance in series.

Comment: I got the voltage rating from an old microwave oven with the voltage rating written on the transformer, and I measrured to open cct voltage of one at about 2.4KV o/c.

Answer (score 0):

To measure the voltage, while operating, I would suggest a string of 9 10MΩ resistors in series with a digital multimeter with a 10MΩ input impedance, or an oscilloscope with a x10 probe. Multiply the reading by 10 for the meter, or 100 for the oscilloscope. NOTE: The x10 probe may not handle 1/10 of the voltage across the magnetron before the filament heats up. Use an extra 9MΩ of resistance instead.

To look at the waveform across the capacitor, where both sides are live, the scope can be set to differential mode like a powerscope, using 2 strings of resistors & both channels, set in A+B mode, with B channel inverted. The trace will be the difference between A & B, with B as the reference (ground or otherwise). To measure the current, you can connect the DMM in series, but make sure it is insulated from ground, & KEEP FINGERS AWAY.
There's big bities in a microwave oven power circuit.